# RANK partition function used in conjunction with SUM OVER

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following which works but I think I've done my usual trick of over complicating something which could be a lot simpler.

If you run the script you will see what I'm trying to achieve - simply a rank initially by Department score and then a rank by each name's score within each department.

How do I simplify the following?:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#Table') IS NOT NULL BEGIN DROP TABLE #Table END;
 CREATE TABLE #Table 
    (
    Department VARCHAR(100),
    Name VARCHAR(100),
    Score INT
    );

INSERT INTO #Table VALUES
('Sales','michaeljackson',7),
('Sales','jim',10),
('Sales','jill',66),
('Sales','j',1),    
('DataAnalysis','jagoda',66),
('DataAnalysis','phil',5),
('DataAnalysis','jesus',6),
('DataAnalysis','sam',79),
('DataAnalysis','michaeljackson',9999);

WITH SumCte AS
    (
    SELECT  Department,
        sm = sum(Score) 
    FROM    #Table
    GROUP BY Department
    )
, RnkDepCte AS
    (
    SELECT  Department,
        rk =RANK() OVER (ORDER BY sm DESC)
    FROM    SumCte
    )
, RnkCte AS
    (
    SELECT  Department,
        Name,
        Score,
        rnk = RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY a.Department ORDER BY a.Score DESC)
    FROM    #Table a 
    )   
SELECT a.Department,
       a.Name,
       a.Score,
       FinalRank = RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ((10000/b.rk) + (100/a.rnk)) DESC)
FROM   RnkCte a 
       INNER JOIN RnkDepCte b 
        ON a.Department = b.Department
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a simpler way.  Try this:

```
select t.*,
       RANK() over (order by sumscore desc, score desc)
from (select t.*,
             SUM(score) over (partition by department) as SumScore
       from #Table t
      ) t
```

Comment: Is there a one level way? i.e. one select sum(rank()) over